# Trying to use CodeCommit remote helper inside Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, aws-codecommit

I've started using git-remote-codecommit to authenticate againts my company's repositories allocated in AWS CodeCommit, so my repo's URI now looks like:

`codecommit://profileName@repoName`

It works perfectly fine when using git in command line: I can clone, pull, push, etc.

My problem is I'm trying to make it work inside Eclipse IDE. Eclipse has no problem reading my local repo and commiting locally, but when trying to fetch it shows a "URI not supported" error. Of course any other operation that requires connecting to the remote repo (pull, push) also fails.

I investigated and it seems some IDE don't support remote helpers for git. As Eclipse is widely used I'm still looking for some way.

So is there any way to make a remote helper work inside Eclipse?

PD: I have the AWS Toolkit plugin installed on my Eclipse, but I don't think it helps in this case.